# Javascript Updating Function If And Else Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the script of a website I'm making, I've got a function that updates as the mouse moves and changes things accordingly. I'm getting it to add text to a div (using innerHTML) if the xValue and yValue of the mouse are in certain positions. However, I'm having two main problems with it.

Firstly, it isn't accepting multiple commands. Ie, I only want the text to be added if it is within certain xValues and less than a certain yValue, for example:

```
    if (480 < xVal < 500 && yVal < 100) {mytextdiv.innerHTML = 'Add my text here';};
```

I've also tried this, but it doesn't work either.

```
    if (xVal < 500 && xVal > 480 && yVal < 100) {mytextdiv.innerHTML = 'Add my text here';};
```

The second issue is that my 'else' clause is causing the whole thing to just not work at all. It stops registering changes in the mouse. As you can see in the example below, even when I change the if function to only have one clause, it still doesn't work.

```
    if (xVal > 480) {mytextdiv.innerHTML = 'Add my text here';};
    else {mytextdiv.innerHTML = '';};
```

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong in either of these cases? Happy to make a JSFiddle with more code if it helps.

Thanks in advance,
Jarrod

Comment: _“The second issue is that my 'else' clause is causing the whole thing to just not work at all. It stops registering changes in the mouse.”_ – not only that, it also produces an error in your browser’s console – so go and check what it has to say.

Comment: It does indeed - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Comment: Try removing the semi-column after the if. And why on earth do you indent your code like that?

Comment: Would usually indent otherwise, formatted that way simply for the sake of minimising space on the question. Removing the semi colon seems to have worked brilliantly btw, thank you for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((xVal < 500) && (xVal > 480) && (yVal < 100)) {mytextdiv.innerHTML = 'Add my text here';}
```

The if-else doesn't work because you put a ";" after the "}",
try this:

```
if (xVal > 480) {mytextdiv.innerHTML = 'Add my text here';}
    else {mytextdiv.innerHTML = '';}
```